# Focusing on the new object

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a chart in my page, When I click on a hyper link, an other detailed chart appears below. Now what i want is, when I click on the link, the focus of the window should goto my new chart which is displayed below the old one. Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: What kind of focus, like this? `document.getElementById('myNewElement').focus()`

Comment: I think the 'focus' here is scroll the window to the element, if I was right, try `window.scrollTo(x_position, y_position)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all folks. This worked well for me.

```
$('.mylink').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var n = $(document).height();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: n },'50');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it will work for u...
 on click on hyperlink call getfocus()

```
 <script>
    function getfocus()
    {
    document.getElementById('yourchart').focus();
    }
 </script>
```